# Alnumsec Style: Duplicate "dot" when referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters

I can't quite figure out, why I get this duplicate "." when referencing with cleverref. I have included a very simple MWE to replicate the error. It might be obvious for those familiar with the alnumsec package.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
showtrims,
a4paper,
oneside,
]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\maxsecnumdepth{subparagraph}
\maxtocdepth{subparagraph}
\usepackage{alnumsec}
\surroundarabic[(][)]{}{.}
\otherseparators{5}
\alnumsecstyle{LRalda}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents* % Print the table of contents
    \cleartoverso
    
    \listoffigures % Print the list of figures
    \cleartoverso
    
    \DoubleSpacing
    \mainmatter
    \pagestyle{Ruled}
    
    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    
    \section{Test Section}
    
    \subsection{Test Sub-Section}
    
    \subsubsection{Test Sub-Sub-Section}
    
    \paragraph{Test Paragraph}
    
    \subparagraph{Test Sub-paragraph}
    
    Reference to \cref{fig:Figure}.
    
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption[Figure Short]{Figure Long}
        \label{fig:Figure}
        \end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've removed the `memoir` tag as this problem can also be done via the `book` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\mainmatter` command of `memoir` does `\@memmain@floats`, which is defined by

```
\newcommand\@memmain@floats{%
   \counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
   \counterwithin{table}{chapter}
}
```

so when `\mainmatter` is issued you get a period after `\thechapter` in the definition of `\thefigure` which adds to the period inserted by `alnumsec`.

Conversely, when `\frontmatter` is executed, figures are numbered by themselves, no prefix.

Hence it's not useful to modify the definition of `\thefigure` in the preamble to remove the surplus period.

How can you solve the issue? Fix the command that does the redefinition mid document.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  showtrims,
  a4paper,
  oneside,
]{memoir}

\usepackage{alnumsec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\maxsecnumdepth{subparagraph}
\maxtocdepth{subparagraph}
\surroundarabic[(][)]{}{.}
\otherseparators{5}
\alnumsecstyle{LRalda}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@memmain@floats{%
   \counterwithin*{figure}{chapter}%
   \counterwithin*{table}{chapter}%
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter\arabic{figure}}%
   \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter\arabic{table}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents* % Print the table of contents
\cleartoverso

\listoffigures % Print the list of figures
\cleartoverso

\mainmatter

\DoubleSpacing
\pagestyle{Ruled}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{Test Sub-Section}

\subsubsection{Test Sub-Sub-Section}

\paragraph{Test Paragraph}

\subparagraph{Test Sub-paragraph}

Reference to \cref{fig:Figure}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption[Figure Short]{Figure Long}
\label{fig:Figure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm quite certain you should load `alnumsec` *before* `cleveref`.

In order to fix the “double period" issue in the headings, add

```
\makepsmarks{Ruled}{%
  \nouppercaseheads
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{ \space}% removed .
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{ \space}% removed .
  \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}%
  \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}%
  \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}%
  \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}%
  \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}%
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}%
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm... only in the header I still have section numbers and chapter numbers followed by two "." - any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Roman I added the trick. My opinion, at this point, is that you shouldn't use `alnumsec` with `memoir`.

Comment: thanks a ton for your solution. I realize now that I abuse a document class for something it is not meant to be used for...